# Coldfusion REST - Serialize Array of CFC

Tags: rest, serialization, coldfusion, cfc, coldfusion-10

Hi I'm trying to serialize an array of CFCs from one of my REST endpoints.  I found this [Example: Array of CFC Serialization](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-5719eac51353e6bb244-7fe7.html)  in the Adobe Help, which pretty much is exactly what I want to do (I can post some code if necessary)  Yet when I try to use `returnType="myCFC[]"` it fails with:

> "Message":"array element type mismatch"

The strange thing is, if I instantiate the same object and call the method from a .cfm file, the cfdump shows the array of objects with data as expected.  But from my AJAX call, the object's property values are all null.  However, if I use return `serializeJSON(myArrayOfCFCs)` the properties have data. But I don't want to have to do that because it will negate the use of content negotiation.

Just curious if anyone has gotten this to work.

update:

```
 <cffunction name="getPatient" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" returntype="Patient[]" produces="text/json" restpath="/{PatientId}">
    <cfargument name="PatientId" type="numeric" required="true" restargsource="Path" />

    <cfset local.response = ArrayNew(1) />
    <cfset local.patient = getPatientGatewayObject().getPatient(PatientId)>

    <cfset local.patientObject = createObject("component", "Patient").init(argumentCollection=queryRowToStruct(local.patient)) />
    <cfset arrayAppend(local.response, local.patientObject) />

    <cfreturn local.response />

 </cffunction>
```

This works, but not what I want in the end:

```
 <cffunction name="getPatient" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" returntype="Patient" produces="text/json" restpath="/{PatientId}">
    <cfargument name="PatientId" type="numeric" required="true" restargsource="Path" />

    <cfset local.response = ArrayNew(1) />
    <cfset local.patient = getPatientGatewayObject().getPatient(PatientId)>

    <cfset local.patientObject = createObject("component", "Patient").init(argumentCollection=queryRowToStruct(local.patient)) />
    <cfset arrayAppend(local.response, local.patientObject) />

    <cfreturn serializeJSON(local.response) />

 </cffunction>
```

Comment: please post what you've tried